# Oracle - Date of Selection on table

Tags: oracle

how to get last date when someone perform selection on table? Last accessed in terms of select statement only not last updated date

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way that I know of is to use auditing. If you just want to audit a single table:

```
AUDIT SELECT ON <tablename>;
```

but there are many other options. See the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF53737 for full details.

NB You must set the parameter `AUDIT_TRAIL` to a value other than `NONE` to actually enable the auditing to take place.